# generate a list of localized language names with links to google translate

Tags: localization, google-translate

I need to generate a list of localized language names from a list of ISO639-1 two-letter language codes. I will wrap them in links to google translate. How hard can this be? It seems like this would be something that google offers by default, but all I can find from google are lists in one language: "English, French, German, etc"

What I need is, "English, Français, Deutch, etc"

Surely someone has already written a javascript / python / php function or similar?

There is a huge list here with localized names: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: I am actually looking for a better resource than that Wikipedia page as well.  One way of doing it is visiting the language page on Wikipedia for each language.  I haven't resorted to that, yet.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) is absolutely a good source for a almost complete language list. In StackOverflow there is an [answer with a list based on Wikipedia with all languages in json format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217492/list-of-language-codes-in-yaml-or-json/4900304#4900304). I wrote a simple function in javascript to get the English and native names for all the languages and published it as a gist: [lang.js](https://gist.github.com/mirontoli/4722797). For your purpose you can simply pass ISO639-1 language code and get the native name for the language:

```
getLanguageNativeName("cv"); // --> "чӑваш чӗлхи"
```