# AVSpeechSynthesisVoice not working for some users

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

In my iOS app most users can hear the `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice` correctly, but some report that it simply does not work. I haven't been able to reproduce the issue locally, but here is how I use the API:

```swift
let sentence = "the sentence to be told"

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: sentence)
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(
  language: "en-GB"
)
utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate * 1.05

synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

This works perfectly fine on iOS 13 (tested most minors), all iOS 14 versions, all the devices I could find... but I keep getting reports of people not getting any audio feedback.

Do you have any pointers on where to look, or at least reproduce the issue?

Comment: Some people have been tripped up by the "soft mute" on iPad - go to the control center and tap the bell icon to toggle this. That could be the problem. Or did you find out any other information about this issue? I am also seeing a similar problem that is NOT due to the soft mute being on.

Comment: I'm having it on my own device, but I haven't been able to figure out what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Does your app support ***localisation***?
I had a similar issue. In my case whenever user changes the app language to Simplified-Chinese the text used to get localised so, I had to change the AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "zh-TW") as well.

You can get the list of languages from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43576853/9855456).

Comment: My app supports localisation, but I'm forcing the speech language to be `"en-GB"` as you can see in the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the API I found that setting the `usesApplicationAudioSession` flag to false in the instance of `AVSpeechSynthesizer`.

Add the following line to your code:

```
synthesizer.usesApplicationAudioSession = false
```

The issue seems to be caused by the device being on 'silent mode'.