# Is it possible to get the client language name just with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I know that I can get the language code via `navigator.language` but is it possible to get the `language name` rather than `language code`.

My expected result can be a string of `"Russian"` or `"Русский"`. Both are fine to me.

Thanks,

Comment: Nope, only the code is available, you have to look that up in a table yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that gets the name

```
function getLang(code) {
    var lang  = code || navigator.language,
        codes = {
            "ab":{
                "name":"Abkhaz",
                "nativeName":"аҧсуа"
            },
            "aa":{
                "name":"Afar",
                "nativeName":"Afaraf"
            },
            "af":{
                "name":"Afrikaans",
                "nativeName":"Afrikaans"
            },
            "ak":{
                "name":"Akan",
                "nativeName":"Akan"
            },
            "sq":{
                "name":"Albanian",
                "nativeName":"Shqip"
            },
            "am":{
                "name":"Amharic",
                "nativeName":"አማርኛ"
            },
            "ar":{
                "name":"Arabic",
                "nativeName":"العربية"
            },
            "an":{
                "name":"Aragonese",
                "nativeName":"Aragonés"
            },
            "hy":{
                "name":"Armenian",
                "nativeName":"Հայերեն"
            },
            "as":{
                "name":"Assamese",
                "nativeName":"অসমীয়া"
            },
            "av":{
                "name":"Avaric",
                "nativeName":"авар мацӀ, магӀарул мацӀ"
            },
            "ae":{
                "name":"Avestan",
                "nativeName":"avesta"
            },
            "ay":{
                "name":"Aymara",
                "nativeName":"aymar aru"
            },
            "az":{
                "name":"Azerbaijani",
                "nativeName":"azərbaycan dili"
            },
            "bm":{
                "name":"Bambara",
                "nativeName":"bamanankan"
            },
            "ba":{
                "name":"Bashkir",
                "nativeName":"башҡорт теле"
            },
            "eu":{
                "name":"Basque",
                "nativeName":"euskara, euskera"
            },
            "be":{
                "name":"Belarusian",
                "nativeName":"Беларуская"
            },
            "bn":{
                "name":"Bengali",
                "nativeName":"বাংলা"
            },
            "bh":{
                "name":"Bihari",
                "nativeName":"भोजपुरी"
            },
            "bi":{
                "name":"Bislama",
                "nativeName":"Bislama"
            },
            "bs":{
                "name":"Bosnian",
                "nativeName":"bosanski jezik"
            },
            "br":{
                "name":"Breton",
                "nativeName":"brezhoneg"
            },
            "bg":{
                "name":"Bulgarian",
                "nativeName":"български език"
            },
            "my":{
                "name":"Burmese",
                "nativeName":"ဗမာစာ"
            },
            "ca":{
                "name":"Catalan; Valencian",
                "nativeName":"Català"
            },
            "ch":{
                "name":"Chamorro",
                "nativeName":"Chamoru"
            },
            "ce":{
                "name":"Chechen",
                "nativeName":"нохчийн мотт"
            },
            "ny":{
                "name":"Chichewa; Chewa; Nyanja",
                "nativeName":"chiCheŵa, chinyanja"
            },
            "zh":{
                "name":"Chinese",
                "nativeName":"中文 (Zhōngwén), 汉语, 漢語"
            },
            "cv":{
                "name":"Chuvash",
                "nativeName":"чӑваш чӗлхи"
            },
            "kw":{
                "name":"Cornish",
                "nativeName":"Kernewek"
            },
            "co":{
                "name":"Corsican",
                "nativeName":"corsu, lingua corsa"
            },
            "cr":{
                "name":"Cree",
                "nativeName":"ᓀᐦᐃᔭᐍᐏᐣ"
            },
            "hr":{
                "name":"Croatian",
                "nativeName":"hrvatski"
            },
            "cs":{
                "name":"Czech",
                "nativeName":"česky, čeština"
            },
            "da":{
                "name":"Danish",
                "nativeName":"dansk"
            },
            "dv":{
                "name":"Divehi; Dhivehi; Maldivian;",
                "nativeName":"ދިވެހި"
            },
            "nl":{
                "name":"Dutch",
                "nativeName":"Nederlands, Vlaams"
            },
            "en":{
                "name":"English",
                "nativeName":"English"
            },
            "eo":{
                "name":"Esperanto",
                "nativeName":"Esperanto"
            },
            "et":{
                "name":"Estonian",
                "nativeName":"eesti, eesti keel"
            },
            "ee":{
                "name":"Ewe",
                "nativeName":"Eʋegbe"
            },
            "fo":{
                "name":"Faroese",
                "nativeName":"føroyskt"
            },
            "fj":{
                "name":"Fijian",
                "nativeName":"vosa Vakaviti"
            },
            "fi":{
                "name":"Finnish",
                "nativeName":"suomi, suomen kieli"
            },
            "fr":{
                "name":"French",
                "nativeName":"français, langue française"
            },
            "ff":{
                "name":"Fula; Fulah; Pulaar; Pular",
                "nativeName":"Fulfulde, Pulaar, Pular"
            },
            "gl":{
                "name":"Galician",
                "nativeName":"Galego"
            },
            "ka":{
                "name":"Georgian",
                "nativeName":"ქართული"
            },
            "de":{
                "name":"German",
                "nativeName":"Deutsch"
            },
            "el":{
                "name":"Greek, Modern",
                "nativeName":"Ελληνικά"
            },
            "gn":{
                "name":"Guaraní",
                "nativeName":"Avañeẽ"
            },
            "gu":{
                "name":"Gujarati",
                "nativeName":"ગુજરાતી"
            },
            "ht":{
                "name":"Haitian; Haitian Creole",
                "nativeName":"Kreyòl ayisyen"
            },
            "ha":{
                "name":"Hausa",
                "nativeName":"Hausa, هَوُسَ"
            },
            "he":{
                "name":"Hebrew (modern)",
                "nativeName":"עברית"
            },
            "hz":{
                "name":"Herero",
                "nativeName":"Otjiherero"
            },
            "hi":{
                "name":"Hindi",
                "nativeName":"हिन्दी, हिंदी"
            },
            "ho":{
                "name":"Hiri Motu",
                "nativeName":"Hiri Motu"
            },
            "hu":{
                "name":"Hungarian",
                "nativeName":"Magyar"
            },
            "ia":{
                "name":"Interlingua",
                "nativeName":"Interlingua"
            },
            "id":{
                "name":"Indonesian",
                "nativeName":"Bahasa Indonesia"
            },
            "ie":{
                "name":"Interlingue",
                "nativeName":"Originally called Occidental; then Interlingue after WWII"
            },
            "ga":{
                "name":"Irish",
                "nativeName":"Gaeilge"
            },
            "ig":{
                "name":"Igbo",
                "nativeName":"Asụsụ Igbo"
            },
            "ik":{
                "name":"Inupiaq",
                "nativeName":"Iñupiaq, Iñupiatun"
            },
            "io":{
                "name":"Ido",
                "nativeName":"Ido"
            },
            "is":{
                "name":"Icelandic",
                "nativeName":"Íslenska"
            },
            "it":{
                "name":"Italian",
                "nativeName":"Italiano"
            },
            "iu":{
                "name":"Inuktitut",
                "nativeName":"ᐃᓄᒃᑎᑐᑦ"
            },
            "ja":{
                "name":"Japanese",
                "nativeName":"日本語 (にほんご／にっぽんご)"
            },
            "jv":{
                "name":"Javanese",
                "nativeName":"basa Jawa"
            },
            "kl":{
                "name":"Kalaallisut, Greenlandic",
                "nativeName":"kalaallisut, kalaallit oqaasii"
            },
            "kn":{
                "name":"Kannada",
                "nativeName":"ಕನ್ನಡ"
            },
            "kr":{
                "name":"Kanuri",
                "nativeName":"Kanuri"
            },
            "ks":{
                "name":"Kashmiri",
                "nativeName":"कश्मीरी, كشميري‎"
            },
            "kk":{
                "name":"Kazakh",
                "nativeName":"Қазақ тілі"
            },
            "km":{
                "name":"Khmer",
                "nativeName":"ភាសាខ្មែរ"
            },
            "ki":{
                "name":"Kikuyu, Gikuyu",
                "nativeName":"Gĩkũyũ"
            },
            "rw":{
                "name":"Kinyarwanda",
                "nativeName":"Ikinyarwanda"
            },
            "ky":{
                "name":"Kirghiz, Kyrgyz",
                "nativeName":"кыргыз тили"
            },
            "kv":{
                "name":"Komi",
                "nativeName":"коми кыв"
            },
            "kg":{
                "name":"Kongo",
                "nativeName":"KiKongo"
            },
            "ko":{
                "name":"Korean",
                "nativeName":"한국어 (韓國語), 조선말 (朝鮮語)"
            },
            "ku":{
                "name":"Kurdish",
                "nativeName":"Kurdî, كوردی‎"
            },
            "kj":{
                "name":"Kwanyama, Kuanyama",
                "nativeName":"Kuanyama"
            },
            "la":{
                "name":"Latin",
                "nativeName":"latine, lingua latina"
            },
            "lb":{
                "name":"Luxembourgish, Letzeburgesch",
                "nativeName":"Lëtzebuergesch"
            },
            "lg":{
                "name":"Luganda",
                "nativeName":"Luganda"
            },
            "li":{
                "name":"Limburgish, Limburgan, Limburger",
                "nativeName":"Limburgs"
            },
            "ln":{
                "name":"Lingala",
                "nativeName":"Lingála"
            },
            "lo":{
                "name":"Lao",
                "nativeName":"ພາສາລາວ"
            },
            "lt":{
                "name":"Lithuanian",
                "nativeName":"lietuvių kalba"
            },
            "lu":{
                "name":"Luba-Katanga",
                "nativeName":""
            },
            "lv":{
                "name":"Latvian",
                "nativeName":"latviešu valoda"
            },
            "gv":{
                "name":"Manx",
                "nativeName":"Gaelg, Gailck"
            },
            "mk":{
                "name":"Macedonian",
                "nativeName":"македонски јазик"
            },
            "mg":{
                "name":"Malagasy",
                "nativeName":"Malagasy fiteny"
            },
            "ms":{
                "name":"Malay",
                "nativeName":"bahasa Melayu, بهاس ملايو‎"
            },
            "ml":{
                "name":"Malayalam",
                "nativeName":"മലയാളം"
            },
            "mt":{
                "name":"Maltese",
                "nativeName":"Malti"
            },
            "mi":{
                "name":"Māori",
                "nativeName":"te reo Māori"
            },
            "mr":{
                "name":"Marathi (Marāṭhī)",
                "nativeName":"मराठी"
            },
            "mh":{
                "name":"Marshallese",
                "nativeName":"Kajin M̧ajeļ"
            },
            "mn":{
                "name":"Mongolian",
                "nativeName":"монгол"
            },
            "na":{
                "name":"Nauru",
                "nativeName":"Ekakairũ Naoero"
            },
            "nv":{
                "name":"Navajo, Navaho",
                "nativeName":"Diné bizaad, Dinékʼehǰí"
            },
            "nb":{
                "name":"Norwegian Bokmål",
                "nativeName":"Norsk bokmål"
            },
            "nd":{
                "name":"North Ndebele",
                "nativeName":"isiNdebele"
            },
            "ne":{
                "name":"Nepali",
                "nativeName":"नेपाली"
            },
            "ng":{
                "name":"Ndonga",
                "nativeName":"Owambo"
            },
            "nn":{
                "name":"Norwegian Nynorsk",
                "nativeName":"Norsk nynorsk"
            },
            "no":{
                "name":"Norwegian",
                "nativeName":"Norsk"
            },
            "ii":{
                "name":"Nuosu",
                "nativeName":"ꆈꌠ꒿ Nuosuhxop"
            },
            "nr":{
                "name":"South Ndebele",
                "nativeName":"isiNdebele"
            },
            "oc":{
                "name":"Occitan",
                "nativeName":"Occitan"
            },
            "oj":{
                "name":"Ojibwe, Ojibwa",
                "nativeName":"ᐊᓂᔑᓈᐯᒧᐎᓐ"
            },
            "cu":{
                "name":"Old Church Slavonic, Church Slavic, Church Slavonic, Old Bulgarian, Old Slavonic",
                "nativeName":"ѩзыкъ словѣньскъ"
            },
            "om":{
                "name":"Oromo",
                "nativeName":"Afaan Oromoo"
            },
            "or":{
                "name":"Oriya",
                "nativeName":"ଓଡ଼ିଆ"
            },
            "os":{
                "name":"Ossetian, Ossetic",
                "nativeName":"ирон æвзаг"
            },
            "pa":{
                "name":"Panjabi, Punjabi",
                "nativeName":"ਪੰਜਾਬੀ, پنجابی‎"
            },
            "pi":{
                "name":"Pāli",
                "nativeName":"पाऴि"
            },
            "fa":{
                "name":"Persian",
                "nativeName":"فارسی"
            },
            "pl":{
                "name":"Polish",
                "nativeName":"polski"
            },
            "ps":{
                "name":"Pashto, Pushto",
                "nativeName":"پښتو"
            },
            "pt":{
                "name":"Portuguese",
                "nativeName":"Português"
            },
            "qu":{
                "name":"Quechua",
                "nativeName":"Runa Simi, Kichwa"
            },
            "rm":{
                "name":"Romansh",
                "nativeName":"rumantsch grischun"
            },
            "rn":{
                "name":"Kirundi",
                "nativeName":"kiRundi"
            },
            "ro":{
                "name":"Romanian, Moldavian, Moldovan",
                "nativeName":"română"
            },
            "ru":{
                "name":"Russian",
                "nativeName":"русский язык"
            },
            "sa":{
                "name":"Sanskrit (Saṁskṛta)",
                "nativeName":"संस्कृतम्"
            },
            "sc":{
                "name":"Sardinian",
                "nativeName":"sardu"
            },
            "sd":{
                "name":"Sindhi",
                "nativeName":"सिन्धी, سنڌي، سندھی‎"
            },
            "se":{
                "name":"Northern Sami",
                "nativeName":"Davvisámegiella"
            },
            "sm":{
                "name":"Samoan",
                "nativeName":"gagana faa Samoa"
            },
            "sg":{
                "name":"Sango",
                "nativeName":"yângâ tî sängö"
            },
            "sr":{
                "name":"Serbian",
                "nativeName":"српски језик"
            },
            "gd":{
                "name":"Scottish Gaelic; Gaelic",
                "nativeName":"Gàidhlig"
            },
            "sn":{
                "name":"Shona",
                "nativeName":"chiShona"
            },
            "si":{
                "name":"Sinhala, Sinhalese",
                "nativeName":"සිංහල"
            },
            "sk":{
                "name":"Slovak",
                "nativeName":"slovenčina"
            },
            "sl":{
                "name":"Slovene",
                "nativeName":"slovenščina"
            },
            "so":{
                "name":"Somali",
                "nativeName":"Soomaaliga, af Soomaali"
            },
            "st":{
                "name":"Southern Sotho",
                "nativeName":"Sesotho"
            },
            "es":{
                "name":"Spanish; Castilian",
                "nativeName":"español, castellano"
            },
            "su":{
                "name":"Sundanese",
                "nativeName":"Basa Sunda"
            },
            "sw":{
                "name":"Swahili",
                "nativeName":"Kiswahili"
            },
            "ss":{
                "name":"Swati",
                "nativeName":"SiSwati"
            },
            "sv":{
                "name":"Swedish",
                "nativeName":"svenska"
            },
            "ta":{
                "name":"Tamil",
                "nativeName":"தமிழ்"
            },
            "te":{
                "name":"Telugu",
                "nativeName":"తెలుగు"
            },
            "tg":{
                "name":"Tajik",
                "nativeName":"тоҷикӣ, toğikī, تاجیکی‎"
            },
            "th":{
                "name":"Thai",
                "nativeName":"ไทย"
            },
            "ti":{
                "name":"Tigrinya",
                "nativeName":"ትግርኛ"
            },
            "bo":{
                "name":"Tibetan Standard, Tibetan, Central",
                "nativeName":"བོད་ཡིག"
            },
            "tk":{
                "name":"Turkmen",
                "nativeName":"Türkmen, Түркмен"
            },
            "tl":{
                "name":"Tagalog",
                "nativeName":"Wikang Tagalog, ᜏᜒᜃᜅ᜔ ᜆᜄᜎᜓᜄ᜔"
            },
            "tn":{
                "name":"Tswana",
                "nativeName":"Setswana"
            },
            "to":{
                "name":"Tonga (Tonga Islands)",
                "nativeName":"faka Tonga"
            },
            "tr":{
                "name":"Turkish",
                "nativeName":"Türkçe"
            },
            "ts":{
                "name":"Tsonga",
                "nativeName":"Xitsonga"
            },
            "tt":{
                "name":"Tatar",
                "nativeName":"татарча, tatarça, تاتارچا‎"
            },
            "tw":{
                "name":"Twi",
                "nativeName":"Twi"
            },
            "ty":{
                "name":"Tahitian",
                "nativeName":"Reo Tahiti"
            },
            "ug":{
                "name":"Uighur, Uyghur",
                "nativeName":"Uyƣurqə, ئۇيغۇرچە‎"
            },
            "uk":{
                "name":"Ukrainian",
                "nativeName":"українська"
            },
            "ur":{
                "name":"Urdu",
                "nativeName":"اردو"
            },
            "uz":{
                "name":"Uzbek",
                "nativeName":"zbek, Ўзбек, أۇزبېك‎"
            },
            "ve":{
                "name":"Venda",
                "nativeName":"Tshivenḓa"
            },
            "vi":{
                "name":"Vietnamese",
                "nativeName":"Tiếng Việt"
            },
            "vo":{
                "name":"Volapük",
                "nativeName":"Volapük"
            },
            "wa":{
                "name":"Walloon",
                "nativeName":"Walon"
            },
            "cy":{
                "name":"Welsh",
                "nativeName":"Cymraeg"
            },
            "wo":{
                "name":"Wolof",
                "nativeName":"Wollof"
            },
            "fy":{
                "name":"Western Frisian",
                "nativeName":"Frysk"
            },
            "xh":{
                "name":"Xhosa",
                "nativeName":"isiXhosa"
            },
            "yi":{
                "name":"Yiddish",
                "nativeName":"ייִדיש"
            },
            "yo":{
                "name":"Yoruba",
                "nativeName":"Yorùbá"
            },
            "za":{
                "name":"Zhuang, Chuang",
                "nativeName":"Saɯ cueŋƅ, Saw cuengh"
            }
        }
    return codes[lang];
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UEjY3/1/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4900304/1066946 ...

Comment: @user1066946 - Yup, that's also the same list where Phil Teare just put the Wikipedia data into JSON, and I just now made a handy function with it.