# How do I translate a locale code to language name using i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I have a language selector in my application that allows users to select their desired display language for the app.  Right now, I only have a few options, but we are planning to add more in the future.  I would like to dynamically generate the settings page language options based on what we translations we have available.

I am very close to a solution, but I'm running into a snag.  I can generate the [list of languages available to i18next using this code](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1068#issuecomment-400573808):

```
const availableLocales = Object.keys(i18next.services.resourceStore.data);
```

but that leaves me with an issue.  I'd like to display the *names* of these languages to the user dynamically, e.g. `en` becomes `English`, `de` becomes `Deutsch` etc.  How can I achieve this?

```js
<RadioGroup
  aria-labelledby="language-select-group"
  value={i18n.language}
  name="language-select-group"
  onChange={handleChange}
>
  {availableLocales.map((languageCode) => (
    <FormControlLabel
      value={languageCode}
      control={<Radio />}
      label={/* TODO: What code goes here? */}
    />
  ))}
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Related question: [How do you convert a language code to the language name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131388/how-do-you-convert-a-language-code-to-the-language-name-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this with native JavaScript using [Intl.DisplayNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DisplayNames).  It's not super pretty, but it is fairly concise, [works on all modern browsers (not including IE)](https://caniuse.com/?search=intl.displaynames) and requires no additional libraries.

```js
<RadioGroup
  aria-labelledby="language-select-group"
  value={i18n.language}
  name="language-select-group"
  onChange={handleChange}
>
  {availableLocales.map((languageCode) => {
    const nameGenerator = new Intl.DisplayNames(languageCode, { type: 'language' });
    const displayName = nameGenerator.of(languageCode);
    return (
      <FormControlLabel
        value={languageCode}
        control={<Radio />}
        label={displayName}
      />
    );
  ))}
</RadioGroup>
```