# Strange behavior using a JSON in meteor

Tags: json, meteor

In my meteor app, I have a JSON file containing this list of languages : [List of Language Codes in YAML or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217492/list-of-language-codes-in-yaml-or-json)

```
Template.myProfile.helpers({
  isoLang: function(){
    return JSON.parse(Assets.getText("myfile.json"));
  }
});

<select>
{{#each isoLang}}
  whaterver i put here
{{/each}}
</select>
```

The problem is that no matter what i return in my helper, as soon as i save the file, my app template change to the login template (im using iron outer), and it don't understand how it's possible.

I tried to get my langauages list as a js object, but from the public folder or the myProfile subfolder (in client folder), it brings me the same problem, and no matter what i try, i never enter my {{#each}} condition.

What am i doing bad in my use of this json / js object ?

Thanks you, David

Comment: I think the problem is because you are using `{{#each}}`. Each is meant for arrays. but that list of languages is a bunch of objects not in array format. so you'd have to convert it to an array of objects. Otherwise if you use `{{#with isoLang}}` you would access each group individually inside the with statement by doing `{{ab}}, {{aa}}, {{af}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [List of Language Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217492/list-of-language-codes-in-yaml-or-json) is neither a JSON array (missing square brackets) nor a (Mongo) cursor. Spacebar's #each is meant

> To iterate over an array or database cursor (cf [Meteor docs](http://goo.gl/pzw5G1) ):

So all you need to transform your JSON object into a JSON array. Here's a basic sketch:

```
var JsonObj= {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"};
var array = []; 
var k = 0
for(var i in JsonObj) {
    if(JsonObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
         array[k++] = JsonObj[i]; 
         console.log(">> " + JsonObj[i])
    }
 }
 console.log(array);
```

Comment: Why not simply `_.toArray`? Meteor comes with Underscore added by default.