# Get Language display name

Tags: javascript, localization

In JavaScript I can get user language code using

```
var code = window.navigator.userLanguage || winodw.navigator.language; //en-US, fr
```

How can I get language display name using this codes. An API would be a preferred option, not static list maintaining all possible codes

Comment: What do you mean by _language display name_ You want to map _en_ to _English_?

Comment: yes, when en-US, I want English. and when fr I want French. possible with API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout the below projects in GitHub,

**language-tags** - https://github.com/mattcg/language-tags

For the underlying JSON data which the above project consumes you can checkout the below project,

**language-subtag-registry** - https://github.com/mattcg/language-subtag-registry

Just in case, if you don't prefer to use the above libraries and you want to have a predefined list of language code/names (on which you can manipulate) you can checkout the below post,

[List of Language Codes in YAML or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217492/list-of-language-codes-in-yaml-or-json)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a direct solution I guess. You can use the following ISO Language code files (JSON,CSV) and read from it.

[ISO Language Code files](http://data.okfn.org/data/core/language-codes)