# List of languages in JSON format (language as a key and code as a value)

Tags: json

If I just can get the list of languages in following JSON format:

```
{
"english": "en",
"german": "de",
"greek": "el",
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217492/list-of-language-codes-in-yaml-or-json#4900304

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{'Abkhaz': 'ab',
 'Afar': 'aa',
 'Afrikaans': 'af',
 'Akan': 'ak',
 'Albanian': 'sq',
 'Amharic': 'am',
 'Arabic': 'ar',
 'Aragonese': 'an',
 'Armenian': 'hy',
 'Assamese': 'as',
 'Avaric': 'av',
 'Avestan': 'ae',
 'Aymara': 'ay',
 'Azerbaijani': 'az',
 'Bambara': 'bm',
 'Bashkir': 'ba',
 'Basque': 'eu',
 'Belarusian': 'be',
 'Bengali': 'bn',
 'Bihari': 'bh',
 'Bislama': 'bi',
 'Bosnian': 'bs',
 'Breton': 'br',
 'Bulgarian': 'bg',
 'Burmese': 'my',
 'Catalan; Valencian': 'ca',
 'Chamorro': 'ch',
 'Chechen': 'ce',
 'Chichewa; Chewa; Nyanja': 'ny',
 'Chinese': 'zh',
 'Chuvash': 'cv',
 'Cornish': 'kw',
 'Corsican': 'co',
 'Cree': 'cr',
 'Croatian': 'hr',
 'Czech': 'cs',
 'Danish': 'da',
 'Divehi; Dhivehi; Maldivian;': 'dv',
 'Dutch': 'nl',
 'English': 'en',
 'Esperanto': 'eo',
 'Estonian': 'et',
 'Ewe': 'ee',
 'Faroese': 'fo',
 'Fijian': 'fj',
 'Finnish': 'fi',
 'French': 'fr',
 'Fula; Fulah; Pulaar; Pular': 'ff',
 'Galician': 'gl',
 'Georgian': 'ka',
 'German': 'de',
 'Greek, Modern': 'el',
 'Guaraní': 'gn',
 'Gujarati': 'gu',
 'Haitian; Haitian Creole': 'ht',
 'Hausa': 'ha',
 'Hebrew (modern)': 'he',
 'Herero': 'hz',
 'Hindi': 'hi',
 'Hiri Motu': 'ho',
 'Hungarian': 'hu',
 'Interlingua': 'ia',
 'Indonesian': 'id',
 'Interlingue': 'ie',
 'Irish': 'ga',
 'Igbo': 'ig',
 'Inupiaq': 'ik',
 'Ido': 'io',
 'Icelandic': 'is',
 'Italian': 'it',
 'Inuktitut': 'iu',
 'Japanese': 'ja',
 'Javanese': 'jv',
 'Kalaallisut, Greenlandic': 'kl',
 'Kannada': 'kn',
 'Kanuri': 'kr',
 'Kashmiri': 'ks',
 'Kazakh': 'kk',
 'Khmer': 'km',
 'Kikuyu, Gikuyu': 'ki',
 'Kinyarwanda': 'rw',
 'Kirghiz, Kyrgyz': 'ky',
 'Komi': 'kv',
 'Kongo': 'kg',
 'Korean': 'ko',
 'Kurdish': 'ku',
 'Kwanyama, Kuanyama': 'kj',
 'Latin': 'la',
 'Luxembourgish, Letzeburgesch': 'lb',
 'Luganda': 'lg',
 'Limburgish, Limburgan, Limburger': 'li',
 'Lingala': 'ln',
 'Lao': 'lo',
 'Lithuanian': 'lt',
 'Luba-Katanga': 'lu',
 'Latvian': 'lv',
 'Manx': 'gv',
 'Macedonian': 'mk',
 'Malagasy': 'mg',
 'Malay': 'ms',
 'Malayalam': 'ml',
 'Maltese': 'mt',
 'Māori': 'mi',
 'Marathi (Marāṭhī)': 'mr',
 'Marshallese': 'mh',
 'Mongolian': 'mn',
 'Nauru': 'na',
 'Navajo, Navaho': 'nv',
 'Norwegian Bokmål': 'nb',
 'North Ndebele': 'nd',
 'Nepali': 'ne',
 'Ndonga': 'ng',
 'Norwegian Nynorsk': 'nn',
 'Norwegian': 'no',
 'Nuosu': 'ii',
 'South Ndebele': 'nr',
 'Occitan': 'oc',
 'Ojibwe, Ojibwa': 'oj',
 'Old Church Slavonic, Church Slavic, Church Slavonic, Old Bulgarian, Old Slavonic': 'cu',
 'Oromo': 'om',
 'Oriya': 'or',
 'Ossetian, Ossetic': 'os',
 'Panjabi, Punjabi': 'pa',
 'Pāli': 'pi',
 'Persian': 'fa',
 'Polish': 'pl',
 'Pashto, Pushto': 'ps',
 'Portuguese': 'pt',
 'Quechua': 'qu',
 'Romansh': 'rm',
 'Kirundi': 'rn',
 'Romanian, Moldavian, Moldovan': 'ro',
 'Russian': 'ru',
 'Sanskrit (Saṁskṛta)': 'sa',
 'Sardinian': 'sc',
 'Sindhi': 'sd',
 'Northern Sami': 'se',
 'Samoan': 'sm',
 'Sango': 'sg',
 'Serbian': 'sr',
 'Scottish Gaelic; Gaelic': 'gd',
 'Shona': 'sn',
 'Sinhala, Sinhalese': 'si',
 'Slovak': 'sk',
 'Slovene': 'sl',
 'Somali': 'so',
 'Southern Sotho': 'st',
 'Spanish; Castilian': 'es',
 'Sundanese': 'su',
 'Swahili': 'sw',
 'Swati': 'ss',
 'Swedish': 'sv',
 'Tamil': 'ta',
 'Telugu': 'te',
 'Tajik': 'tg',
 'Thai': 'th',
 'Tigrinya': 'ti',
 'Tibetan Standard, Tibetan, Central': 'bo',
 'Turkmen': 'tk',
 'Tagalog': 'tl',
 'Tswana': 'tn',
 'Tonga (Tonga Islands)': 'to',
 'Turkish': 'tr',
 'Tsonga': 'ts',
 'Tatar': 'tt',
 'Twi': 'tw',
 'Tahitian': 'ty',
 'Uighur, Uyghur': 'ug',
 'Ukrainian': 'uk',
 'Urdu': 'ur',
 'Uzbek': 'uz',
 'Venda': 've',
 'Vietnamese': 'vi',
 'Volapük': 'vo',
 'Walloon': 'wa',
 'Welsh': 'cy',
 'Wolof': 'wo',
 'Western Frisian': 'fy',
 'Xhosa': 'xh',
 'Yiddish': 'yi',
 'Yoruba': 'yo',
 'Zhuang, Chuang': 'za'}
```

Comment: Why downvote? This is the format he is asking for

Comment: Actually, maybe it isn't.  Some of the lines in your JSON have multiple names in the key field with commas between them.

Comment: yeah it has multiple names in some of the lines but I can edit that and separate them it will take few minutes. Atleast @Yusuf saved me for writing this complete list my self, Thanks!